# Add HTML content after link with specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to add some HTML after a link that has a specific class.

Well - this does not work:

```
a.mylinkclass:after { 
    content: "<div class='uk-badge'>Test</div>";
    color: green;
}
```

`content` does not allow HTML. So what other possibilities do I have to add HTML to a link with a specific tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this (using `jQuery`)

```js
$("<div class='uk-badge'>Test</div>").insertAfter('a.mylinkclass');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='' class='mylinkclass'>mylinkclass 1</a>
<a href='' class='myotherclass'>myotherclass</a>
<a href='' class='mylinkclass'>mylinkclass 2</a>
<a href='' class='myotherclass'>myotherclass</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript, instead of CSS, to add the HTML after the link.

For example, you could use JQuery to do it: (as i see your question is tagged with)

```
$("a.mylinkclass").after("<div class='uk-badge'>Test</div>");
```